# Drawing OpenCV contours and save as transparent image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to draw contours i have found using findContours.

If i draw like this, i get a black background with the contour drawn on it.

```
    out = np.zeros_like(someimage)
    cv2.drawContours(out, contours, -1, 255, 1)
    cv2.imwrite('contours.png',out)
```

If i draw like this, i get a fully transparent image with no drawn contours.

```
    out = np.zeros((55, 55, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(out, contours, -1, 255, 1)
    cv2.imwrite('contours.png',out)
```

How do i go about making an image with size (55,55) and draw a contour on this, while keeping a transparent background?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with transparent images in OpenCV you need to utilize the fourth channel after BGR called alpha with controls it. So instead of creating a three-channel image, create one with four channels, and also while drawing make sure you assign the fourth channel to 255.

```
mask = np.zeros((55, 55, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, cnts, -1, (255, 255, 255, 255), 1) #change first three channels to any color you want.
cv2.imwrite('res.png', mask)
```

[image: INput]

Input image whose contours to draw.

[image: result]

Result

Comment: Damn, that was simple.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV. I am using a white blob on black background for input, since I do not have a contour image available. The contour image needs to be grayscale.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('mask.png')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

out = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
out[:,:,3] = gray

# write output
cv2.imwrite('mask_transp.png',out)

# display it
cv2.imshow("out", out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Transparent result (download to see it since it is white on transparent background):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Python/OpenCV, use the black and white image as the alpha channel as well as using it for a 3 channel BGR image.

```
cntr_img = np.zeros((55, 55, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(cntr_img, contours, -1, 255, 1)
out = cv2.cvtColor(cntr_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
out[:,:,3] = cntr_img
cv2.imwrite('contours.png',out)
```

Comment: I've tried this out = cv2.cvtColor(cntr_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA).
But it gives me this error
"Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 4".

I'm loading someimage like this
someimage = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)